# Shell completion dependent on arguments already provided

Tags: python, click, command-line-interface

I was wondering if it's possible using Click 8 to implement shell completion may depend on commands, options, and arguments that have already been specified earlier on the command line. I see that `ctx.params` does not include them, however. In any case, consider the following example.

```
./foo.py --global-opt foo my_command --command-opt <TAB>
```

I am wondering how to have tab completion for `--command-opt` depend on the value of `--global-opt` (a callback, i.e. global, option). Ideally, one could do the usual processing for `--global-opt` first, before doing shell completion for `--command-opt`.

In fact, I was told by one of the maintainers that this is possible, but he failed to explain how. Any advice or example would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do it from within the script, but you can define a separate completion file to be used by bash. More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1800/how-to-specify-a-custom-autocomplete-for-specific-commands)

Comment: @Marat Thanks, though I was hoping there was a nicer solution specific to Click that leverages the usual processing machinery of Click.